# How to pass a fieldset to javascript?

Tags: javascript, fieldsets

When my user clicks a button, I want to access the fieldset by javascript. Can i do that?

```
  <apex:commandbutton value="Send"  onClick="check('{$ObjectType.Customization__c.FieldSets.Fields_for_fieldChooser}')" />
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function check(apiNameList) {

        for (var i = 0; i < apiNameList.length; i++) {
            var apiName = apiNameList[i];
            console.log(apiNameList[i]);

            var updateVal = apiName + "_update";
            var deleteVal = apiName + "_delete";
            var dontaddVal = apiName + "_do_not_add";
            //    if ( document.getElementById(updateVal).checked === false && document.getElementById(deleteVal).checked === false && document.getElementById(dontaddVal).checked === false){
            alert("Please choose an option for each field");
            break;

            //     }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you are a stickler for delimiters or have an IE userbase, this snippet plays nicely inside the repeat: `<apex:outputText rendered="{!fields[0] != field}">,</apex:outputText>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get quotes round the field names so you have a JavaScript array of strings, you need to turn the Apex array into a JavaScript array by for example using an `apex:repeat`:

```
<apex:page>
<script>
var fields = [
<apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.Customization__c.FieldSets.Fields_for_fieldChooser}">
    '{!f}',
</apex:repeat>
];
</script>
</apex:page>
```

The above Visualforce produces this:

```
<script>
var fields = [
    'Field1__c',
    'Field2__c',
   ' Field3__c',
];
</script>
```

Then adapt you other JavaScript to reference this array. (Note that the spurious trailing comma is allowed in JavaScript).

Or if you need the JavaScript arrays to be inline, this will work:

```
... onClick="check([<apex:repeat var="f" value="{!$ObjectType.TestRelationship__c.FieldSets.TestFieldSet}">'{!f}', </apex:repeat>])" ...
```

Comment: If you are a stickler for delimiters or have an IE userbase, this snippet plays nicely inside the repeat: `<apex:outputText rendered="{!fields[0] != field}">,</apex:outputText>`